# XSD complexType with mix content not supported in ADB - axis2 wsdl2Java

Tags: apache-axis, wsdl2java

Getting this error when try to generate java classes from wsdl file.

WSDL File Path : https://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/TDSServices/GetReservationRQ/GetReservation_1.19.16.wsdl

Using axis2 1.7.2 for generating classes

Command used to generate is axis2/bin/wsdl2java.sh -uri https://files.developer.sabre.com/wsdl/sabreXML1.0.00/TDSServices/GetReservationRQ/GetReservation_1.19.16.wsdl

[image]

Answer (score 0):

ADB does not support multiple type , i.e ADB does not provide a way to represent mixed content in the generated Java classes, so it is not able to handle this type of schema.

After adding "mixed=false" problem is resolved for me.

Example

```
<complexType name="ObjectType" mixed="false">
```